# What is the communication protocol used by non-expansion card USB ports to communicate with CPU?

Tags: usb, communication, cpu, protocol, usb-host

USB ports can come as expansion cards, like this:

[image]

Now obviously, since this is a PCIe USB card, the communication protocol used by this expansion card to communicate with CPU is PCIe.

But what about USB ports connected to USB headers, like this:

[image]

Or the ones soldered on the motherboard found at the back of the PC and on laptops, like these:

[image] [image]

How do the last three communicate with the CPU? Do they also use PCIe? If not, then what protocol do they use?

Comment: Plug a device into one and follow the IO routing in Device Manager or your regional equivalent.

Comment: Open up your Windows Device Manager. Click 'View' on the menu bar and choose 'Devices by connection'. Start expanding the various device trees until you find your USB ports - it's likely that you'll find them parented to a PCIe controller of some sort - probably one embedded into the "Root Complex" in the motherboard's chipset.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Just like on the card, the USB wires go to USB host controller, which is a separate chip on motherboard or built in to the chipset. So it could be PCIe, or anything else, which depends on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard USB ports are typically from the chipset:

[image]

For Intel, the chipset connects to the CPU over DMI lanes, which are essentially PCIe lanes. The actual electrical interface is what Intel calls a HSIO lane:

[image]

Which can be multiplexed between PCIe, USB or other buses.  Logically to the OS all of this looks like a PCI device:

[image]

So to answer your question, the protocol these use is PCI, and electrically PCI is sent over various internal connections that are functionally pretty close to PCIe.

(Source is Intel's chipset documentation: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/chipsets/desktop-chipsets/z790-chipset-brief.html)